# Java - authorization by certificates

Tags: java, ssl, https

I've got a problem with certificates in my java application which I cannot solve by myself.

I have got:

1. private key: priv.key
2. public certificate: pub.crt
3. ALPHA_CA_root.pem - certificate which allows to communicate over https.

When I use curl like this, it works:

```
curl -v https://server.com --cert pub.crt --key priv.key --cacert ALPHA_CA_root.pem -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"json", "jsonContent"}'
```

But when importing the keystore I receive error and communication is not established. I'm importing the certificates as follows:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in pub.crt -inkey priv.key -out client.p12 -name "sc"
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass password
keytool -import -alias gridserverSSL -file ../ALPHA_CA_root.pem -storepass password-keystore keystore.jks
```

After, I set the java parameters in my application:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

The application uses Apache httpClient to establish communication with the server. In my error log I see something like that:

```
cause javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Can anyone help ? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: where do you put keystore.jks ? have you tried to provide the full path to your jks instead of the file name ?

Comment: My keystore.jks is in application main folder. I will try the solution you have provided but I think that the applications sees the keystore. When I remove the keystore.jks from application main folder the error log logs message that the app could not find the keystore.jks.

Answer (score 0):

If the certificates at step (3) are part of the signing chain, which isn't clear, they need to be combined with the certificate at (2) and all imported at the same time, along with the private key, under the same alias.

If they are trusted CA entries for verifying peer certificates, they should be in the truststore, not the keystore where the private key is, and they should be imported with `keytool -trustcacerts`.

Comment: unfortunately it still does not work. I've tried: 
openssl pkcs12 -export -in pub.crt -inkey priv.key -CAfile ALPHA_CA_root.pem -out client.p12 -name "alias"

still the same error occurs.
Also added ALPHA_CA_root.pem to truststore. Same story :(

The funny thing is that this works:
curl -v https://server.com --cert pub.crt --key priv.key --cacert ALPHA_CA_root.pem -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"json", "jsonContent"}'

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve the problem. 
I had to add ale the certs from here:
https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1223298-alphassl-intermediate-certificates